# How to check whether a tuple of variables leads to a match in a second list of tuples?

Tags: r, list, pattern-matching

I have a data frame `d1` with observations at certain locations `l` and times `t`.

```
> head(d1, 3)
  id   l    p          t         X
1  1 258 2016 2016-01-05 -1.158644
2  5 261 2016 2016-01-14  1.604873
3  2 261 2016 2016-01-20 -1.102002
```

In another data frame `p2` I have time intervals `t1:t2` for the locations `l`, and I want to check row by row if the tuples of `d1` match location and time interval tuples of `p2`.

```
> head(p2, 3)
    l    p         t1         t2
1 261 2016 2016-01-11 2016-01-25
2 261 2017 2017-02-27 2017-03-13
3 261 2017 2017-03-01 2017-03-15
```

In the positive case, a dummy variable `d1$match` should be given the value 1, in the negative case 0:

```
# [1] 0 1 1 ...
```

My attempt so far is, first, to collapse `l` and `p` of both data frames into strings and compare them, and second, to check if `t` lies in `t1:t2`.

However, the code I came up with is a bit awkward, and it only works more or less if the periods do not overlap, as in `p1`. Moreover warnings are also issued because there seem to be problems with the `"Date"` classes.

```
> p1
    l    p         t1         t2
1 261 2016 2016-01-11 2016-01-25
2 261 2017 2017-02-27 2017-03-13
4 258 2018 2018-01-09 2018-01-23

p <- p1
p.strg <- sapply(1:nrow(p), function(x) {
  do.call(paste, c(p[x, c("l", "p")], sep = "|"))
})

sapply(1:nrow(d1), function(x) {
  strg <- do.call(paste, c(d1[x, c("l", "p")], sep = "|"))
  t.d <- d1[x, "t"]
  t.p <- p[which(p.strg %in% strg), c("t1", "t2")]
  return(as.integer(any(p.strg %in% strg) & t.d >= t.p[1] &
                      t.d <= t.p[2]))
})

# [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
# There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
# warnings()
# Warning messages:
#   1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   Incompatible methods ("Ops.Date", "Ops.data.frame") for ">="
#   ...
```

If the periods do overlap as in `p2`,

```
p <- p2
p.strg <- sapply(1:nrow(p), function(x) {
  do.call(paste, c(p[x, c("l", "p")], sep = "|"))
})
sapply(1:nrow(d1), function(x) {
  strg <- do.call(paste, c(d1[x, c("l", "p")], sep = "|"))
  t.d <- d1[x, "t"]
  t.p <- p[which(p.strg %in% strg), c("t1", "t2")]
  return(as.integer(any(p.strg %in% strg) & t.d >= t.p[1] &
                      t.d <= t.p[2]))
})
```

it won't work at all:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I think I'm a little lost. What would be a better approach to address this problem *in base R*?

*Note:* My original data is somewhat more extensive (d1: 20000 x 11, p2: 1700 x 8), so I need an efficient solution.

---

*Data:*

```
d1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L), l = c(258, 261, 261, 260, 258, 260, 261, 
261, 259, 260, 261, 258, 259, 261, 261), p = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018), t = structure(c(16805, 16814, 16820, 16924, 17193, 17211, 
17227, 17229, 17348, 17481, 17517, 17543, 17554, 17787, 17887
), class = "Date"), X = c(-1.15864442153663, 1.60487335898257, 
-1.10200153102672, -0.823719007033067, 1.20944271845298, 0.790388149166713, 
-1.0996495357495, -0.421449225963478, -0.243567712934607, -0.337415580767635, 
-1.64590022554026, 2.11206142393207, -0.950235138478342, -2.08164602167738, 
-1.88576409729638), match = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

p1 <- structure(list(l = c(261, 261, 258), p = c(2016, 2017, 2018), 
    t1 = structure(c(16811, 17224, 17540), class = "Date"), t2 = structure(c(16825, 
    17238, 17554), class = "Date")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L
), class = "data.frame")

p2 <- structure(list(l = c(261, 261, 261, 258, 259, 261), p = c(2016, 
2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018), t1 = structure(c(16811, 17224, 
17226, 17540, 17551, 17884), class = "Date"), t2 = structure(c(16825, 
17238, 17240, 17554, 17565, 17898), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "match  ....  time interval tuples of p2"  Do you mean match either number exactly? Or fall in the interval defined by the numbers?

Comment: @Elin E.g. in the given example row 2 and 3 of `d1` I consider matches of (first row of) `p1`, `l`-  and `p`-tuples of the former match the `l`- and `p`-tuples of the latter, and `t` falls is the interval `t1:t2`. (A *3*-tuple would match a "*2*-tuple-with-interval-hybrid".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a raw solution that uses loops:

```
d1[["match"]] <- 0L
for (i in seq_len(nrow(d1))) {
  p2rows <- which(p2[["l"]] == d1[["l"]][i])
  for (r in p2rows) { # If no location match, there will be nothing to loop over
    if (d1[["t"]][i] >= with(p2[r,], t1) && d1[["t"]][i] <= with(p2[r,], t2)) {
      d1[["match"]][i] <- 1L
      break # Enough to find one match, we break out of the inner loop
    }
  }
}

   id   l    p          t          X match
1   1 258 2016 2016-01-05 -1.1586444     0
2   5 261 2016 2016-01-14  1.6048734     1
3   2 261 2016 2016-01-20 -1.1020015     1
4   3 260 2016 2016-05-03 -0.8237190     0
5   1 258 2017 2017-01-27  1.2094427     0
6   3 260 2017 2017-02-14  0.7903881     0
7   4 261 2017 2017-03-02 -1.0996495     1
8   5 261 2017 2017-03-04 -0.4214492     1
9   2 259 2017 2017-07-01 -0.2435677     0
10  3 260 2017 2017-11-11 -0.3374156     0
11  5 261 2017 2017-12-17 -1.6459002     0
12  1 258 2018 2018-01-12  2.1120614     1
13  2 259 2018 2018-01-23 -0.9502351     1
14  4 261 2018 2018-09-13 -2.0816460     0
15  4 261 2018 2018-12-22 -1.8857641     1
```

*Edit*: A slightly faster version:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(d1))) {
  p2rows <- which(p2[["l"]] == d1[["l"]][i])
  if (any(d1[["t"]][i] >= with(p2[p2rows,], t1) & d1[["t"]][i] <= with(p2[p2rows,], t2))) {
    d1[["match"]][i] <- 1L
  }
}
```

*Edit 2*: Again something that should be slightly faster:

```
library(data.table)
sapply(
  seq_len(nrow(d1)), 
  function(i) {
    p2rows <- which(p2[["l"]] == d1[["l"]][i])
    as.integer(any(between(d1[["t"]][i], p2[p2rows, "t1"], p2[p2rows, "t2"])))
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. It's rather slow though.

Comment: Sure. There is definitely a number of steps you can take to make this faster, see my update for a slight improvement.

Comment: @jay.sf, There is a second update now, again slightly faster code.